# How can I make conditional rendering properly in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

recently, I am making my web application with a react and I'm struggling with a small issue(not small for me)

Below is my app.js and I want to conditional render NAV component by login/out status.
(as you can see it is outside Switch!)

```
<>

      <Nav indexStatus={indexStatus} setIndexStatus={setIndexStatus} />
      
      <Index indexStatus={indexStatus} setIndexStatus={setIndexStatus} />

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Auth(LandingPage,null)}/>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Auth(LoginPage,false)}/>
        <Route exact path="/calendar" component={Auth(Calendar,true)} />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={Auth(About,false)} />
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Auth(RegisterPage,false)}/>
      </Switch>
      
    </>
```

to check login status I gave true/false value to localStorage when user login/out

login:

```
dispatch(loginUser(body))
    .then(response=>{
      if(response.payload.loginSuccess){
        localStorage.setItem('user',response.payload.loginSuccess)
        props.history.push("/")
       console.log(props.parentNode)
       
       
      }else{
        alert('login failed')
      }
    })
```

logout:

```
 axios.get("/api/users/logout")
    .then(res=>{
      if(res.data.success){
        console.log(res)
       history.push('/login')
       localStorage.setItem('user','false')

        
    }else{
        alert("Logout failed")

    }
  })
}
```

and I gave localStorage value to state like below:

```
const [loginStatus,setLoginStatus] =useState(localStorage.getItem('user'))
```

I check it with console.log  and it works fine

so I used ?: operator to do conditional render my component

```
loginStatus==false ? 
  <div>
  <div className="nav">
    <h2>TITLE</h2>
    <div className="buttons">
      <div>About</div>
      <div>How to use</div>
      <button onClick={logoutHandler}>Logout</button>

    <StyledLink to="/login"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSignInAlt}/></StyledLink>
    
    
      <button onClick={()=>setIndexStatus(!indexStatus)} >Index</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


:
  <div>
  <div className="nav">
    <h2>TITLE</h2>
    <div className="buttons">
      <div>About</div>
      <div>How to use</div>
      <button onClick={logoutHandler}>Logout</button>

    <StyledLink to="/login"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSignInAlt}/></StyledLink>
    <StyledLink to="/register"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserPlus}/></StyledLink>
    
      <button onClick={()=>setIndexStatus(!indexStatus)} >Index</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, It doesn't work at all even tho I changed option like loginstatus ===true or
loginstatus ? etc.

Can you tell me what's wrong with my logic or coding?
thx for reading this
your help will be appreciated.

Comment: {loginStatus === true ? (some code) :  (other code)}. Did you add the {} braces ?

Comment: I just tried and I got syntax errors?

Comment: what was the error? can you please add screenshot?

Comment: uhmm idk how to upload screenshot on comment

Comment: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  37 |
  38 |   return (
> 39 |     {loginStatus === false ? (
     |                  ^
  40 |       <div>
  41 |       <div className="nav">
  42 |         <h2>TITLE</h2>

Comment: The data returned from local storage is if type string. You need to watch for that in your comparison. You may check like loginStatus === 'true'

Comment: could you please update in the question body what you have tried, plus also add full component.

Comment: @AbuSufian oh nvm I made a mistake I didn't put it in fragment tag and I did it but it still doesn't work

Comment: @SanishJoseph thanks! it worked but only when I logged in/out and refresh if i don't refresh page it doesn't work

Comment: could you please console.log(loginStatus) and can see what you are getting?

Comment: @AbuSufian it literally says true when I logged in and says false when I logged out

Comment: @AbuSufian I edited question! you can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68968514/why-my-component-doesnt-re-render-itself-even-tho-i-used-useeffectreact-js

Comment: You probably want to call `setLoginStatus` somewhere, and also fix the string / boolean conversion issues. Also please create a [mre].