# Why my component doesn't re-render itself even tho I used useEffect?(React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

recently, I am making my web application with a react and I'm struggling with a small issue(not small for me)

Below is my app.js and I want to conditional render NAV component by login/out status.
(as you can see it is outside Switch!)

```
<>

      <Nav indexStatus={indexStatus} setIndexStatus={setIndexStatus} />
      
      <Index indexStatus={indexStatus} setIndexStatus={setIndexStatus} />

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Auth(LandingPage,null)}/>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Auth(LoginPage,false)}/>
        <Route exact path="/calendar" component={Auth(Calendar,true)} />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={Auth(About,false)} />
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Auth(RegisterPage,false)}/>
      </Switch>
      
    </>
```

to check login status I gave true/false value to localStorage when user login/out

login:

```
dispatch(loginUser(body))
    .then(response=>{
      if(response.payload.loginSuccess){
        localStorage.setItem('user',response.payload.loginSuccess)
        props.history.push("/")
       console.log(props.parentNode)
       
       
      }else{
        alert('login failed')
      }
    })
```

logout:

```
 axios.get("/api/users/logout")
    .then(res=>{
      if(res.data.success){
        console.log(res)
       history.push('/login')
       localStorage.setItem('user','false')

        
    }else{
        alert("Logout failed")

    }
  })
}
```

and I gave localStorage value to state like below:

```
const [loginStatus,setLoginStatus] =useState(localStorage.getItem('user'))
```

I check it with console.log  and it works fine

so I used useEffect to chanege loginStatus value, and re-render only localstorage has changed

```
const checkLoginStatus= localStorage.user
  useEffect(()=>{
    
    if(checkLoginStatus==='true'){
      setLoginStatus(true)
    }else{
      setLoginStatus(false)
    }
  },[checkLoginStatus])
  console.log(localStorage.user)
```

Finally, I wrote my code with ?: operator like below

```
return (
    <>
    {loginStatus ===true ? (
      <div>
      <div className="nav">
        <h2>TITLE</h2>
        <div className="buttons">
          <div>About</div>
          <div>How to use</div>
          <button onClick={logoutHandler}>Logout</button>

        <StyledLink to="/login"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSignInAlt}/></StyledLink>
        
        
          <button onClick={()=>setIndexStatus(!indexStatus)} >Index</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>)

    
    :
     ( <div>
      <div className="nav">
        <h2>TITLE</h2>
        <div className="buttons">
          <div>About</div>
          <div>How to use</div>
          <button onClick={logoutHandler}>Logout</button>

        <StyledLink to="/login"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSignInAlt}/></StyledLink>
        <StyledLink to="/register"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserPlus}/></StyledLink>
        
          <button onClick={()=>setIndexStatus(!indexStatus)} >Index</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    )}
    </>

    
    
 
  
   
   );
     }

export default Nav
```

However, the problem is it only works partly, I have to refresh pages to work component conditional rendering. I'm not sure why is it like this even tho I used useEffect with second paramater [checkLoginStatus]

Can you tell me why is not work properly? and how my logic is wrong?
Thx for reading, your help will be appreciated

Comment: When checkLoginStatus will be update? If you are thinking when localStorage.user change then I think this is where you are wrong.

Comment: Local storage is pretty passive. You can set/get values basically. Is the code in your question all one single component? You should use the React state to track current authentication status, initialize from local storage and persist to local storage. Local storage isn't meant to ***be*** the state. You still need to update React state and/or props to trigger React to rerender the component and read from localStorage again to get the current value.

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for your specific answer. well can you recommend me a way to upadte state then? i am pretty new at coding and I don't have a clue to do that tbh

Comment: Sure, no problem. I feel like I would need to see a complete code example first since it's not clear where these code snippets live relative to one another. From what I can tell, you could move the `loginStatus` state into the component render the routes and the `Nav` component and pass down the state and update as props to the components that need them. What is that `Auth` HOC doing?

Comment: useEffect won't help you. You should use [StorageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent) to subscribe to changes because local storage is passive (either you read or write)

Comment: @DrewReese okay since I can't upload all of my files here this is my git hub address I think you can check those files in client/components folder address: https://github.com/awesomeji/orgranziedproject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to lift the `loginStatus` state up to the `App` parent component so the state and updater function can be passed down to children components to read and/or update.

App

Move the `loginStatus` state to this parent component. Pass the `loginStatus` to the `Nav` component for it to handle its conditional rendering, and pass `setLoginStatus` to the `Login` component for it to update the state. Notice that the routes were reordered so they no longer need to specify the `exact` prop everywhere, they aren't wrapped with the `Auth` HOC as this likely creates a new component each render cycle, and now the `Login` component is rendered on the `render` prop so we can slip in additional props.

```
const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(
  () => !!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")),
);

return (
  <>
    <Nav
      indexStatus={indexStatus}
      loginStatus={loginStatus} // <-- pass login status
      setIndexStatus={setIndexStatus}
      setLoginStatus={setLoginStatus} // <-- pass updater
    />
  
    <Index indexStatus={indexStatus} setIndexStatus={setIndexStatus} />

    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/login"
        render={props => <LoginPage {...props} setLoginStatus={setLoginStatus} />}
      />
      <Route path="/calendar" component={Calendar} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
      <Route path="/" component={LandingPage} />
    </Switch>
  </>
);
```

Nav

Remove the `loginStatus` state and use the passed `loginStatus` value and `setLoginStatus` function to update the state in the parent.

```
function Nav({ indexStatus, loginStatus, setLoginStatus, setIndexStatus }) {
  const history = useHistory();

  const logoutHandler = () => {
    ...
    setLoginStatus(false); // <-- logged out
  };

  return loginStatus ? (
    ...
  )
  : (
    ...
  );
}
```

LoginPage

Access the `setLoginStatus` state updater function from props and set when user logs in successfully. Decorate the export with the `Auth` HOC (***this should be done for all the components needing it***).

```
function LoginPage(props) {
  ...

  const onSubmitHandler=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();

    let body={
      email: Email,
      password: Password
    };

    dispatch(loginUser(body))
      .then(response=>{
        if(response.payload.loginSuccess){
          localStorage.setItem('user',response.payload.loginSuccess)
          props.setLoginStatus(true); // <-- set logged in
          props.history.push("/");
        } else {
          alert('login failed');
        }
      });
  }

  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  );
}

export default Auth(withRouter(LoginPage));
```

#### Update

The reason your components that aren't receiving passed props is because the `Auth` HOC isn't passing them through.

```
export default function(SpecificComponent, option, adminRoute = null) {
  ...
  function AuthenticationCheck(props) { // <-- props
    ...
    return (
      <SpecificComponent /> // <-- not passed through
    );
  }
  return AuthenticationCheck
}
```

Should be

```
export default function(SpecificComponent, option, adminRoute = null) {
  ...
  function AuthenticationCheck(props) { // <-- props
    ...
    return (
      <SpecificComponent {...props} /> // <-- passed through
    );
  }
  return AuthenticationCheck
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your specific help! I will try it when i can use my laptop by the way What i wanted is showing different nav component on webpage by login/out status and that’s why i used ?: operator. but isn’t && operator in your code only show nav component when user logged in and not when user logout?and if it’s right do you think i can solve it to make 2 nav components (one is just nav and the othet is for user) and render those in app.js with ?: operator?  Just let me know if i think in wrong way  and appreciate for your help again

Comment: @user15508209 I looked at your `Nav` component and it had only a `logoutHandler` handler and you rendered  nearly the same JSX for both cases, so I figured that was mistake. Sounds like I assumed incorrectly. I'll update answer.

Comment: thank you for your kindness. I didn't make it too different because I wanted to complete conditional render first. haha and I also have a small isuue. I tried

Comment: <Route
        path="/login"
        render={props => <LoginPage {...props} setLoginStatus={setLoginStatus} />}
      />

Comment: above one but it keeps saying props.setLoginStatus is not a fuction. I also console.log(props) but couldn't find setLoginStatus in anywhere

Comment: https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-pass-props-to-components/

Comment: https://ui.dev/react-router-v5-pass-props-to-components/

Comment: as you can check the above links, the way pass props to component in router has changed. since I use react-router-dom v5.2.0, I tried "<Route path="/login"><LoginPage setLoginStatus={setLoginStatus}/></Route> " too  but it still doesn't work

Comment: @user15508209 Either way works in v5. I don't see why it shouldn't be available on the props object in `LoginPage`. Have you updated the code in your repo, or can you create a running codesandbox (import from github) that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: well I just uploaded github you can check there and i tried to make codesandbox but something went to wrong and it didn't work

Comment: Issue is here `function LoginPage(props,{setLoginStatus})`... React components receive only the single `props` argument. Use `props.setLoginStatus`.

Comment: I did it at the first place and it didn't work that's why i tried to use {} just in case

Comment: I console.log(setLoginStatus) in "logoutPage" and it says it is function :/

Comment: however when I console.log(props.setLoginStatus) in "loginPage" it says it is undefined

Comment: I gave another states as props(indexStatus,setIndexStatus,loginStatus) to login page  and console.log it all of it is undefined and I decalre something for test(const test = 'test') and gave it to login page too but it also turns out undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236553/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-user15508209).